# Postgresql select row with minimum value by certain column?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I've data like this

```
id  student  grade subject
-----------------------------
0   Amy      5     Art History
1   Amy      2     Ethics
2   Jhon     7     Calculus
3   Joe      4     Poetry
4   Joe      2     Cooking
5   Jhon     2     PE
```

Find out everyone's lowest scores

```
Results 
--------------
1   Amy      2     Ethics
5   Jhon     2     PE
4   Joe      2     Cooking
```

**Tried Solution**

```
SELECT *, min(grade)
FROM data
GROUP BY student
```

I get error `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate...`

Comment: What if they have their lowest score `5` in two subjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not worrying about ties, then use the PostgreSQL extension for [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, student, grade, subject
FROM table
ORDER BY id, grade;
```